# How to test if the browser support <input capture />

Tags: javascript, html, browser

How could I test if the current browser support the  feature of mobile browsers to use the device camera to take a picture?

https://addpipe.com/html-media-capture-demo/

Capture is basically ignored in all desktop browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=html-media-capture

How could I detect if I can use capture (and that it won't show an open file dialog, but will actually open the picture application)?

Comment: Theoretically, if you add that attribute to your HTML, you should be able to inspect the `capture` property of the `input` element in JavaScript. If it is anything other than `undefined`, it is supported.

Comment: You can use Modernizr.js - see the documentation here: https://modernizr.com/docs

Comment: Note this is behavior [specified in the standard](https://w3c.github.io/html-media-capture/), to wit: "The capture IDL attribute MUST reflect the respective content attribute of the same name." This stipulation is defined for most attributes such that you can always know, by checking the value of the corresponding attribute, if it is supported.

Comment: The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) of image capture suggests that it may still open a file dialog, but the dialog could include a "Camera" button to switch from picking a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an input element in JS and test for the `capture` property. It will be undefined if unsupported.

```js
var el = document.createElement('input')
var supported = el.capture != undefined

console.log('capture supported: '+supported)
```

Here's what it looks like in the iOS simulator

[image]

Comment: It works fine as it is, but it won't if I use Typescript 3.8 in Angular 9... if I set the attribute `capture` to an element, it will be set, regardless it is supported or not... :'(

Comment: but the detector part of this solution does not set it. it creates a default `input` element and only queries whether or not the property is there. so not a factor IMO, works fine

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following function:

```
function supported(attribute) {
   var i = document.createElement('input');
   i.setAttribute(attribute, true);
   return !!i[attribute];
}
```

And you can call it, like `supported('capture')`, or if you want to test for the `accept` attribute `supported('accept')`

> **Source: http://anssiko.github.io/html-media-capture/**